# Use PreferenceActivity and save preferences in ContentProvider, how?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-contentprovider, android-preferences

Jeff Sharkey in [this post](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/09/11/quick-database-row-editor-in-android-09-sdk/) shows how to create save application preferences in database by hack on PreferenceActivity.

It said i can use a ContentProvider, too.

Can you give me an example on how to save preferences from PreferenceActivity to ContentProvider?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ContentProvider` is a sort of coding protocol how to access data from various storage types, such as data from database, files, xml, fetched from network etc.

I would not search for this example as it's not advised for Preferences. Just stick either with the inbuilt way, or how you have seen on the linked resources.